# How do I echo %myvariable% into a txt file from batch without giving an permanent value

Tags: batch-file, text, echo

I am making something that writes a program into text file and converts into a batch script.
I need to print `"if %startmenu%==1 Goto Tutorial"` into the text file but I get this:

```
If Echo is off==1 Goto Tutorial
```

And I don't want to set the variable to be permanent because it is a user menu.

```
Echo Echo [1] Tutorial >> C:\"Offline Server"\"Local Data Base"\Config\RawServer.cmd
Echo Echo [2] Upload >> C:\"Offline Server"\"Local Data Base"\Config\RawServer.cmd
Echo Echo [3] Download >> C:\"Offline Server"\"Local Data Base"\Config\RawServer.cmd
Echo Echo [4] Exit >> C:\"Offline Server"\"Local Data Base"\Config\RawServer.cmd
Echo Set /P StartMenu >> C:\"Offline Server"\"Local Data Base"\Config\RawServer.cmd
Echo If %StartMenu%==1 Goto Tutorial
```

The last line is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, he last line should have >> C:\"Offline Server"\"Local Data Base"\Config\RawServer.cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double the percent-signs:

```
Echo If %%StartMenu%%==1 Goto Tutorial >> file
```